# Visual Studio 2022 wont save the option for prompt for check out

Tags: visual-studio-2022

My problem is when I change the option from the Checked-in Items in the option menu to give a Prompt for check out it wont save when I close my Visual Studio.

at this point i need to change my options every time I turn on my VStudio.